# Mysql binary logs filling up and crashing the server

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how I got myself into this one. I have a master-slave replication going on a lamp stack application. This is what we had today. The drop in the black line is me clearing by issuing `PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE_SUB( NOW( ), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);`

[image]

my.cnf on the master machine -- the one with the log filling problem -- reads as follows. I'm expiring logs after 3 days.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# sync
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
expire_logs_days = 3
max_binlog_size  = 100M
ssl
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/newcerts/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/newcerts/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/newcerts/server-key.pem



[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid



# sync config
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=app_database
server-id=1
~                                                                                                                                           
~                                                                                                                                           
~
```

Comment: Have you looked at what's in the binlogs, with the `mysqlbinlog` utility?  That would be the thing to do, first... I routinely generate multiple GB of binlogs per day on some systems... as expected. But if this is a new problem, take a look in the logs and see what's generating so much activity.  Use the options `--base64-output=decode-rows` and `--verbose`